# When setting isExcludedFromBackup, file write fails in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, icloud

I am setting the `isExcludedFromBackup` flag to prevent a file in the `Application` Support directory from getting backed up.

When I set this URL property, my writes fail saying "file ... does not exist".

If I do not set the property, then the write creates the file and everything works. If the file already exists, subsequent writes with the flag set seem to work fine.

I am using the `Data.write(to: url, options: .atomic)` API to write the file.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the answer...

As soon as [setResourceValues(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/url/1779940-setresourcevalues) is called, the resource values are written to disk. The file needs to exist when it's called, or else the call fails. This was not intuitive to me.

Comment: Agreed, I got bit by this too. Also feels a bit ugly that it is a property on the URL and not a file (`FileWrapper` or `FileHandle`) itself... and that the URL has to be mutable.